# Jet propulsion underwater - How to create bubbles

Tags: modeling

I am working on a project right now again in which I am having a pretty futuristic looking submarine underwater, working with jet propulsion. I want the blast pipes to spit out blue light, which is no problem, but I will also need many many different sized crowded bubbles behind them.

Just to give you guys an idea what kind of look I am after:

https://st4.depositphotos.com/1813545/21750/i/1600/depositphotos_217500626-stock-photo-underwater-swimmer-sea-air-jet.jpg

https://previews.123rf.com/images/zefart/zefart1806/zefart180600754/102834854-air-bubbles-from-jacuzzi-jet-in-bubbly-blue-water-in-a-thermal-spa-pool-abstract-background.jpg

The end result is going to be a still image, so I have not  planned to animate anything.

And for all questions and further insight, the image I am working on. Still far from finished, but I want to collect some ideas on this:
[image]

Thanks for reading and for any ideas! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, create a single bubble by making a sphere and making it a glass material, or however you want the bubble to look.

Add a particle system to the engine and under render, change the default halo to object, and under object, select your bubble
[image]

To make each of the bubbles a different size, change the scale randomness to something higher like 1.

[image]

To change the velocity of the bubbles, change the direction you want them to flow under the velocity tab.

[image]

There are many more settings you can change like turning gravity on and off. Good Luck!

Comment: Thank you a lot for the quick answer Caleb, I’ll be sure to check this out! :)